# Defining a user with props or deconstruction in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

New to React and am trying to figure how I can add/define `{user}`within my code below. I simply keep getting an error on `user not defined` when I try to run it.

My Code currently:

```
import React from 'react';
import {
  Media,
  Dropdown,
  DropdownToggle,
  DropdownMenu,
  DropdownItem,
} from 'reactstrap';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';

class UserPreview extends React.Component {
  toggle = ({user}) => this.setState({DropdownOpen: !this.state.DropdownOpen});

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <tr className="user">
          <td>
            <Media>
              <img
                alt={`${user.name} avatar`}
                className="avatar d-flex mr-3"
                src={user.url} />
              <Media body>{user.name}</Media>
            </Media>
          </td>
          <td>
            <Dropdown isOpen={this.state.DropdownOpen} toggle={this.toggle(this)}>
              <DropdownToggle caret>
                Admin
              </DropdownToggle>
              <DropdownMenu>
                <DropdownItem>Read</DropdownItem>
                <DropdownItem>Write</DropdownItem>
              </DropdownMenu>
            </Dropdown>
          </td>
          <td><Button color="warning">Delete</Button></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

UserPreview.propTypes = {
  user: PropTypes.shape({
    name: PropTypes.string,
    // TODO: add an url proptype.
    url: PropTypes.string,
  }).isRequired,
};

export default UserPreview;
```

Comment: Are you trying to access `this.props.user` inside the `toggle` function? I'm unclear where you want `user` to come from.

Comment: User was coming from another component called from proptypes.

Comment: Please do not edit your question such that it invalidates existing answers. Instead, create a new question.

Answer (score 2):

```
<Media>
      <img
            alt={`${user.name} avatar`}
            className="avatar d-flex mr-3"
            src={user.url} />
      <Media body>{user.name}</Media>
</Media>
```

This is the row the error is throwing from, since in the toggle function you're not using the `user` param.

you need to:

```
<Media>
      <img
            alt={`${this.props.user.name} avatar`}
            className="avatar d-flex mr-3"
            src={this.props.user.url} />
      <Media body>{this.props.user.name}</Media>
</Media>
```

Or just extract the `user` prop at the beginning of the `render` method like:

```
render() {
    let { user } = this.props;
    .
    .
    .
```

Also:

```
<Dropdown isOpen={this.state.DropdownOpen} toggle={this.toggle(this)}>
```

The `toggle` prop of the `Dropdown` component should be a reference to a function and you are calling the function so the `toggle` prop is actually `undefined` since the `toggle` method doesn't return any value.

You should pass the `toggle` prop like this:

```
<Dropdown isOpen={this.state.DropdownOpen} toggle={this.toggle}>
```

And if you want the `user` to be sent as argument to the `toggle` method you should do it this way:

```
<Dropdown isOpen={this.state.DropdownOpen} toggle={this.toggle.bind(this, this.props.user)}>
```

and then you don't need the deconstruction so the `toggle` method can look like this:

```
toggle = (user) => this.setState({DropdownOpen: !this.state.DropdownOpen});
```